# Lookup column with dates in PowerPivot

Tags: excel, powerpivot, dax

I need to add a column on a table, computed from another one but I can't get the formula right.
Here are the tables and columns:

```
Table 1
Date (date)

Table 2
Key (text)
Start (date)
End (date)
```

I want to add a column to the Table 1 which will contains the Key from Table 2 where the Date column is between Start and End from Table 2.

If the date cannot be found in a range, then the field should be blank.

Comment: Somthing like that: =CALCULATE(Table2[Key]; FILTER(Table2; [Date]>=Table2[Start]&&[Date]<=Table2[End]))

Comment: I've tried other formulas more or less like this one, but none worked...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try creating a calculated column in Table1 called Key and use this expression:

```
=
CALCULATE (
    LASTNONBLANK ( Table2[Key], 0 ),
    FILTER ( Table2, Table1[Date] >= Table2[Start] && Table1[Date] <= Table2[End] )
)
```

> I am assuming in your table2 there is no overlaps between dates and
>   every date in Table1 will match only one start-end range.

It is not tested but should work, let me know if this works for you.

Comment: Perfect ! I knew I wasn't so far !